# How to stop text from vertically centering in a table?

Tags: html, css, styles, center

Here is the html code that makes the table:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="profile">
        <img src="http://www.teleread.com/wpcontent/uploads/2009/05/image18.png" />
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the css:

```
.profile img {
    width: 120px;
    height: 125px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    border: 1px #cc1212 solid;
    clear: both;
}
```

Here is the code in action on jsfiddle:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/Yeqnn/
```

THE ISSUE: The word "Hello" is vertically centered in the right column

How do I fix this? BTW, the image has to be in the table and floated left to work with my current theme... any ideas, if so drop an answer plz.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply put `vertical-align: top;` on your `<td>` elements.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Yeqnn/2/)

Comment: i never heard of that atribute before :P